# Does TLP controls laptop FAN?

Tags: fan, fancontrol, tlp

I've installed TLP on my laptop.

And I found when plug out AC jack(Adaptor), the FAN goes off.
I want to turn the FAN off also in AC mode, but I can't find some related option in /etc/default/tlp.

Which option can be off the FAN?
And does TLP manages FAN control relative to device's temperature?(example like when it goes up to 40 C, FAN goes on etc..)

regards.

Comment: check your bios settings, it may have an option of turning fan off.

Comment: I checked already, but I didn't find any options relative..

Comment: But before using TLP, when plug out adaptor, it still operated. I'm very curious about this..

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133890/how-can-i-control-fan-speed-on-acer-nitro-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to find an option to manage the fan in your laptop's BIOS. Most laptops (especially consumer laptops) will not allow you to do that, and some may only allow you to force the fan to run at full speed.

`tlp` does not manage fan control, and besides, most laptops do not expose fan control abilities or even give fan speed readings to the OS.

Comment: I did it aleady, but I didn't found any options relative with "FAN".

Comment: Nevertheless, with tlp installed the fan does not work. Before installing it, the fan worked. I have also installed lm-sensors, but it doesn't find the fan. I've installed also the fancontrol package, but still nothing.